# конвертация utf-8 в windows-1251

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка

У меня есть кириллический текст в UTF8, который отображается нормально.
Мне нужно изменить кодировку на windows-1251 так, чтобы кириллический текст так же нормально отображался. И вот что-то не могу понять, как это сделать?

Comment: Отображался где? Нужно сообщать желаемую кодировку тому, кто отображает

Comment: Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696481/encoding-conversation-utf-8-to-1251-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js имеет несколько встроенных средств для конвертации, но, к сожалению, для вашего случая они не подойдут.

1. [`buffer.transcode()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_transcode_source_fromenc_toenc) конвертирует в обе стороны, но только для стандартных кодировок, с которыми обычно и так можно справиться при помощи модуля `fs`.
2. [`TextDecoder`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/util.html#util_class_util_textdecoder) в последних версиях Node.js (которые компилируются с полной поддержкой ICU) может читать (декодировать) большой набор кодировок, в том числе `'windows-1251'`. Однако [`TextEncoder`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/util.html#util_class_util_textencoder) может кодировать текст только в UTF-8.

Поэтому вы можете воспользоваться [низкоуровневым кодированием](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696481/encoding-conversation-utf-8-to-1251-in-javascript) из ссылки в комментариях. Или же использовать одну из библиотек, например популярную [`iconv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv) или её облегчённый и ускоренный вариант [`iconv-lite`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite).